# Does "absorbing" in different directions have different effects?

Tags: absolver

In the Khalt style, you're told that you can press the right stick up, down, left, or right to "absorb" attacks. No matter which direction you press, you seem to do the same animation, glowing blue and holding a pose for a brief moment.

Is there any difference in how this functions based on what direction you press, or is it only based on timing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From brief personal experience (Windfall all the way), as well as from multiple users in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/absolver/comments/6vqxh7/why_is_the_forsaken_style_considered_the_most/), it looks like the Khalt style is considered (by the game) to be the easiest to master precisely *because* you don't have to pick a correct direction to "absorb" hits in. Any direction works, as long as you've gotten the timing right.

> Khalt's absorb is omni directional meaning that as long as you got the timing down you will pull of the move.
>
> [Khalt] seems like the easiest, since there's no directional concerns like the other two defensive skills